# Best Practices to write Python for three different scripts

Tags: python, python-2.7

I got a project and before I begin. I thought to take experts suggestions.

Below is the project requirement:

> I have to write three different scripts say script 1, script 2, script
>   3. Few of the variable values are same for three different scripts. So I planned include one more script say common-script so all the common
>   variable values are declared in common-script.
>
> 1. Script 1 may need a different variables values those are not required to script 2 and script 3 - similarly for script 2 and script
>      3.

Below are the my question.

> 1. Shall I include only common variables values in common-script and declare non common variables in their script itself (Script 1 specific
>      variables declare in script 1 itself not in common-script and
>      similarly for script 2 and script 3).
> 2. Or shall I declare all the inputs and variables of the script 1, script 2, and script 3 in common-script file itself and then call
>      variables  values to scripts 1, 2 and 3?

Which option is best or any other standards I need to follow?

> 3. The other requirement is I have to ask user to run all the scripts that is script 1 followed by   script 2, script 3 or he want to run
>      only specific script that is, he/she get options to select script 1,
>      script 2, script 3. What is the best practices to implement these
>      kind?
> 4. Still now I used only functions and write the separate scripts and import as modules. For these project first time I am planning to use
>      python classes.

I need your tips how to use classes in this project and I have no idea on the classes for now. But i am start reading documents.

Answer (score 2):

This question is similar to Object-oriented programming: you can have a base class which defines some attributes and the sub-classes which inherit the base class and redefine attributes. It's up to you to choose.

But, what your are doing is a kind of configuration file.

I think the best practice is to define all the common variables in a common script. That way you can document them all in one place. This is better to maintain.

The other scripts can redefine only what they need.

**common.py**

```
#: This is my var 1
VAR1 = "thing1"

#: This is my var 2
VAR2 = "thing2"
```

**script1.py**

```
from .common import *

VAR2 = "another thing2"
```

Comment: what is the meaning of the '.' before the 'common'?

Comment: Relative import. Read the doc: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would recommend is to declare a class.
Classes are a "clean" way to share variables between functions and running those functions in the appropriate order. You could build your class like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
  def __init__(self):
    # in the constructor, initialize your shared variables
    self.mySharedVar_1 = 0
    self.mySharedVar_2 = []
    # and so on

  def oldScript1(self,script1InputParam_1, script1InputParam_2):
    # here you implement what was in script1 with
    # variables that are specific to script1
    myScript1Var_1 = 0
    # example operation using a shared variable and a script1 variable
    myScript1Var_2 = myScript1Var_1 + self.mySharedVar_1

    return myScript1Var_2

  def oldScript2(self,script2InputParam_1):
    # same as for script1

  def oldScript3(self,script3InputParam_1):
    # again, same as for script1

  def run(self):
    # here you run the methods in the appropriate order, using the outputs of one script as the input to another
    outputScript1 = self.oldScript1(1,2)
    outputScript2 = self.oldScript2(outputScript1)
    # and so on for script3
```

Then in the main script, all you need to write is:

```
import MyClass

myInstance = MyClass() # you can specify constructor values if necessary
myInstance.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

**For the project requirement question:** What do you mean with "variable values"? If you have some "global" variables (like for example, a file path or a constant) that are the same for the 3 scripts, and you are not very comfortable with classes, i suggest to create a config file which will be given to each script.
Then you could change these values in the respective scripts:
**conf.py file:**

`#config file: global values
GLOBAL_1 = "some_string"
GLOBAL_2 = 215 # some number`

**script1.py** *(works also for script2.py and script3.py)*

`from .conf import *
new_variable = GLOBAL_2 + 542 # new operation using global value`

**For question number 3:** The best and nicer way is to provide options to select script 1, script 2, script 3. For exemple you declare a function of options like:
Consider we want to pass two file names through command line and we also want to give an option to check the usage of the script. Usage of the script is as follows −

`usage: test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>`

Here is the following script to test.py −

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, getopt
def main(argv):
    inputfile = ''
    outputfile = ''
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:o:",["ifile=","ofile="])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print 'test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>'
        sys.exit(2)
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-h':
            print 'test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>'
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
            inputfile = arg
        elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
            outputfile = arg
    print 'Input file is "', inputfile
    print 'Output file is "', outputfile

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

**For question 4:**
Sure classes is a good way of programming in python, but it is not the easiest way to answer your common-variables questions.